# Clock is not ticking with sample time input (without getting system time)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, clock

I want to start the countdown timer from x date/time to y date/time.
The output should change with every second.
The code is working fine if i want to use it in a static format but i want it to be dynamic.
The time should tick without anyone having to reload it.

I'm beginner in Javascript and React. Need some help.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


export class Clock extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        let fixDate = new Date("December 8, 2019 00:00:00"); 
        let currDate = new Date("December 4, 2019 00:00:00");
        this.state = { fixDate, diff: fixDate - currDate };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.timerID = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timerID);
    }
    tick() {
        this.setState({
            currDate: new Date(December 4, 2019 00:00:00")
        });
    }
    render() {
        const { diff } = this.state;
        const days = Math.abs(Math.floor(diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
        const totalhours = Math.floor(diff / (60 * 60 * 1000));
        const plusminus = totalhours % 24;
        const hours = Math.abs(totalhours % 24);
        const mins = Math.floor((diff - (totalhours * 60 * 60 * 1000)) / (60 * 1000));
        const secs = Math.floor((diff - (totalhours * 60 * 60 * 1000) - (mins * 60 * 1000)) / 1000);
        if (plusminus < 0) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h2>Past {days} Days {hours} Hours {mins} Mins {secs} Secs</h2>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h2>{days} Days {hours} Hours {mins} Mins {secs} Secs to go</h2>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the output of 
`4 Days 0 Hours 0 Mins 0 Secs to go` ,
But it should change every second.

Comment: You can really simplify date calculation using moment.js : https://momentjs.com/

Comment: `currDate: new Date(December 4, 2019 00:00:00")` has missing `"`

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are not changing the value of `diff` in state. `diff` was only set in constructor.

Also the output was not changed every second because on each `tick()` you are not changing the value of `currDate`.

So instead, we can set `currDate` and find value of `diff` just before rendering the component.

See the sample below (Although it is not matching your expected output of 4days!).

```js
class Clock extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        let fixDate = new Date("December 8, 2019 00:00:00"); 
        let currDate = new Date();//"December 4, 2019 00:00:00");
        this.state = { fixDate, currDate };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.timerID = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timerID);
    }
    tick() {
        this.setState({
            currDate: new Date()//"December 4, 2019 00:00:00")
        });
    }
    render() {
        const { fixDate, currDate } = this.state;
      const diff = fixDate - currDate;
       //console.log(diff);
        const days = Math.abs(Math.floor(diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
        const totalhours = Math.floor(diff / (60 * 60 * 1000));
        const plusminus = totalhours % 24;
        const hours = Math.abs(totalhours % 24);
        const mins = Math.floor((diff - (totalhours * 60 * 60 * 1000)) / (60 * 1000));
        const secs = Math.floor((diff - (totalhours * 60 * 60 * 1000) - (mins * 60 * 1000)) / 1000);
        if (plusminus < 0) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h2>Past {days} Days {hours} Hours {mins} Mins {secs} Secs</h2>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h2>{days} Days {hours} Hours {mins} Mins {secs} Secs to go</h2>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Clock></Clock>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
</div>
```